# Adding "bleed area" to 2 canvases?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I have an app that has a "bleed area" on a canvas. I'd like to apply this to 2 canvases now. I've tried using `activeCanvas` and even setting `canvas1` to see if I couldn't get it to work on even the first canvas, but I seem to be mucking it up somehow.

I do get an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: canvas1 is not defined`.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var activeCanvas, front, back;

$(document).ready(function() {
  canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('front');
  canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('back');
  canvas1.setHeight(360);
  canvas1.setWidth(208);
  canvas2.setHeight(360);
  canvas2.setWidth(208);
  changeView(1);
});

function changeView(value) {
  if (value == 1) {
    activeCanvas = canvas1;
    $('#front').parent().css('display', 'block');
    $('#back').parent().css('display', 'none');
  }

  if (value == 2) {
    activeCanvas = canvas2;
    $('#front').parent().css('display', 'none');
    $('#back').parent().css('display', 'block');
  }
}

function dropText() {
  var text = new fabric.Text('test');
  activeCanvas.add(text);
}


var padding = 20;
canvas1.on('object:moving', function(e) {
  var obj = e.target;
  
  // if object is too big ignore
  if (obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height - padding * 2 ||
      obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width - padding * 2) {
      return;
  }
  obj.setCoords();

  // top-left corner
  if (obj.getBoundingRect().top < padding ||
    obj.getBoundingRect().left < padding) {
      obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top - obj.getBoundingRect().top + padding);
      obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left - obj.getBoundingRect().left + padding);
  }
  
  // bot-right corner
  if (obj.getBoundingRect().top + obj.getBoundingRect().height > obj.canvas.height - padding || 
    obj.getBoundingRect().left + obj.getBoundingRect().width > obj.canvas.width - padding) {
      obj.top = Math.min(
        obj.top,
        obj.canvas.height - obj.getBoundingRect().height + obj.top - obj.getBoundingRect().top - padding);
      obj.left = Math.min(
        obj.left,
          obj.canvas.width - obj.getBoundingRect().width + obj.left - obj.getBoundingRect().left - padding);
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeView(1);">Front</button>
<button onclick="changeView(2);">Back</button>
<button onclick="dropText();">Add Text</button>

<div style="text-align: center">
  <canvas id="front"></canvas>
  <canvas id="back"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your canvas event handler inside document ready function. The problem was it trying to add event listener to canvas1 before document loaded,that time it not created fabric canvas. So it was throwing error.

```js
var activeCanvas, front, back,canvas1,canvas2;
$(document).ready(function() {

  canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('front');
  canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('back');
  canvas1.setHeight(360);
  canvas1.setWidth(208);
  canvas2.setHeight(360);
  canvas2.setWidth(208);
  changeView(1);

  var padding = 20;
  canvas1.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    var obj = e.target;

    // if object is too big ignore
    if (obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height - padding * 2 ||
        obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width - padding * 2) {
        return;
    }
    obj.setCoords();

    // top-left corner
    if (obj.getBoundingRect().top < padding ||
      obj.getBoundingRect().left < padding) {
        obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top - obj.getBoundingRect().top + padding);
        obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left - obj.getBoundingRect().left + padding);
    }

    // bot-right corner
    if (obj.getBoundingRect().top + obj.getBoundingRect().height > obj.canvas.height - padding || 
      obj.getBoundingRect().left + obj.getBoundingRect().width > obj.canvas.width - padding) {
        obj.top = Math.min(
          obj.top,
          obj.canvas.height - obj.getBoundingRect().height + obj.top - obj.getBoundingRect().top - padding);
        obj.left = Math.min(
          obj.left,
            obj.canvas.width - obj.getBoundingRect().width + obj.left - obj.getBoundingRect().left - padding);
    }
  });
});

function changeView(value) {
  if (value == 1) {
    activeCanvas = canvas1;
    $('#front').parent().css('display', 'block');
    $('#back').parent().css('display', 'none');
  }

  if (value == 2) {
    activeCanvas = canvas2;
    $('#front').parent().css('display', 'none');
    $('#back').parent().css('display', 'block');
  }
}

function dropText() {
  var text = new fabric.Text('test');
  activeCanvas.add(text);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeView(1);">Front</button>
<button onclick="changeView(2);">Back</button>
<button onclick="dropText();">Add Text</button>

<div style="text-align: center">
  <canvas id="front"></canvas>
  <canvas id="back"></canvas>
</div>
```

To add bleed area for both the canvas:-

You are passing the function as anonymous, name it like `onObjectMoving()` then add to `canvas1.on('object:moving',onObjectMoving);canvas2.on('objec‌​t:moving',onObjectMo‌​ving);`

```js
var activeCanvas, front, back,canvas1,canvas2;
$(document).ready(function() {

  canvas1 = new fabric.Canvas('front');
  canvas2 = new fabric.Canvas('back');
  canvas1.setHeight(360);
  canvas1.setWidth(208);
  canvas2.setHeight(360);
  canvas2.setWidth(208);
  changeView(1);

  var padding = 20;
  canvas1.on('object:moving', onObjectMoving);
  canvas2.on('object:moving', onObjectMoving);
  function onObjectMoving(e) {
    var obj = e.target;

    // if object is too big ignore
    if (obj.currentHeight > obj.canvas.height - padding * 2 ||
        obj.currentWidth > obj.canvas.width - padding * 2) {
        return;
    }
    obj.setCoords();

    // top-left corner
    if (obj.getBoundingRect().top < padding ||
      obj.getBoundingRect().left < padding) {
        obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top - obj.getBoundingRect().top + padding);
        obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left - obj.getBoundingRect().left + padding);
    }

    // bot-right corner
    if (obj.getBoundingRect().top + obj.getBoundingRect().height > obj.canvas.height - padding || 
      obj.getBoundingRect().left + obj.getBoundingRect().width > obj.canvas.width - padding) {
        obj.top = Math.min(
          obj.top,
          obj.canvas.height - obj.getBoundingRect().height + obj.top - obj.getBoundingRect().top - padding);
        obj.left = Math.min(
          obj.left,
            obj.canvas.width - obj.getBoundingRect().width + obj.left - obj.getBoundingRect().left - padding);
    }
  };
});

function changeView(value) {
  if (value == 1) {
    activeCanvas = canvas1;
    $('#front').parent().css('display', 'block');
    $('#back').parent().css('display', 'none');
  }

  if (value == 2) {
    activeCanvas = canvas2;
    $('#front').parent().css('display', 'none');
    $('#back').parent().css('display', 'block');
  }
}

function dropText() {
  var text = new fabric.Text('test');
  activeCanvas.add(text);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.20/fabric.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeView(1);">Front</button>
<button onclick="changeView(2);">Back</button>
<button onclick="dropText();">Add Text</button>

<div style="text-align: center">
  <canvas id="front"></canvas>
  <canvas id="back"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great. One issue: Why am I not able to edit text in your example?

Comment: Edit text??  You are creating fabric.Text object. Create fabric.IText object

Comment: Scratch that! Sorry. I forgot to have it be IText. Fixed my own side problem, haha. Thanks for your help, you're a life saver.

Comment: Do you know how I might apply the bleed area to both canvases?

Comment: You are passing the function as anonymous, name it like `onObjectMoving() ` then add to `canvas1.on('object:moving',onObjectMoving);canvas2.on('object:moving',onObjectMoving);`

Comment: Would you mind please updating your code above to elaborate on what you mean? I would really appreciate it. I've tried incorporating your last comment but am not having any luck.

Comment: that's very helpful. I see what you meant now.  Cheers